# Git rebase with overwrite

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am trying to get my master changes into my local branch by doing

```
git checkout MyPersonalBranch
git rebase master
```

then I get the error

```
 Patch failed at ..blah blah
When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

When I try `git rebase --continue` I get the error

```
xxx.client.jar: needs merge
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add
```

I want it to keep the xxx.jar in MyPersonalBranch. How do I tell git not to try to merge this one file?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the xx.jar" and not merge it? Also rebase isn't a merge. It's a replay of the changes

Comment: I want to replace the original jar with my jar. I don't want it to compare the binary's contents.

Comment: Again, there is no merge occuring, its rewinding your commits and then replaying them after fast-forwarding HEAD. Exactly how you do that is going to vary based upon your sequence of commits, how many times you edit the jar etc.  I strongly suggest you go read the GIT book git-scm.com/book to understand what you are doing.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be tracking Java `.jar` files in `git`. There's not a particularly useful way to difference them, patch them, compare them, merge disparate changes to them, etc...

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can use the `--strategy` option to specify how conflicts should be handled. The strategy `theirs` blindly replaces files.

However, in your case, you've only got a single file. You really won't want to use the `theirs` strategy for all files. Instead, after you get the message to resolve the conflict, you can checkout that one specific file from the branch:

```
git checkout <branch> yourfile
```

(At that point, `<branch>` still refers to the branch as it was before the rebase started.)

Comment: I get `error: path myfile is unmerged` so in my case `<branch>` seems to be `HEAD`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the file contents are correct, then `git add` it and continue the rebase.